# how to pass value to input hidden in modal box jquery and laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

help how to pass value to input hidden to modal box when click the submit button

my view:

```
<button **data-report-name="customer-list"** type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete-modal" class="btn btn-primary" {{ in_array('customer-list', $choosedReports) ? 'disabled' : '' }}>Add Report
</button>
```

modal box:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Are you sure want to choose this selected data?</p>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="report_name"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Put it directly in your question for easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

A very general way to do it, listen for the click event for the button with the given data parameter and then add it to the input with the given name.

```js
$('button[data-report-name]').on('click', function() {
 $('input[name="report_name"]').val($(this).attr('data-report-name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-report-name="test-report">Submit</button>
<input value="" name="report_name"/>
```

**Note:** I have removed the "hidden" type for easier demo.